# React Datepicker exclude past time

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

**I am currently working on a project with a bus booking system. How to exclude the past time of the day or disable the past time, to not be able to select booking?**

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  showTimeSelect
  minDate={new Date()}
  timeFormat="HH:mm"
  timeIntervals={60}
  timeCaption="time"
  excludeTimes={[
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 17),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 18),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 19),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 20),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 21),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 22),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 23),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 24),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 0),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 1),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 2),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 3),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 4),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 5),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 6),
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 7),
  ]}
  dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
  showDisabledMonthNavigation
  required
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer was worked for me:

```
 setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), getHours(new Date())
```